# PHP post variable showning in DOM but not on page?

Tags: php, ajax, post, request

i have two files first is a.php and second is b.php (popup)

in a.php i am posting data via ajax

```
    $.post("b.php",{cat:"hello"},function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

and in b.php i am using

```
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
echo $cat;
```

### In DOM of a.php, "hello" is showing, but in b.php it is blank. why???

In a.php i am using

```
$('div#showrqmt').on('click',function(){

    $.post("b.php",{cat:"hello"},function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});

<div class="upbtntopmain uploadaudio"  href="javascript:void(0)"     id="showrqmt"><a class="pnkbtnb_n">Show Requirments</a></div> (this will popup     b.php)
```

In response text of ajax the post data ("hello") is showing but not in php

in b.php i have used

```
$cat = $_REQUEST['cat']; // not working
$cat = $POST['cat']; //not working
echo $cat // for both case not working...
```

Comment: You need to explain what exactly is blank. `b.php` does not generate a HTML document, so it's not clear what "DOM" you were looking at.

Comment: It isn't clear where in the DOM of `a.php` "hello" is showing either (I'm *guessing* you mean as part of a text node inside a `<script>` element).

Comment: I don't understand why you describe b.php as a popup. There's no code in the question that could create a popup. You're making a POST request using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: You said "(this will popup     b.php)" — it won't with the code you've shared.

Comment: "In response text of ajax the post data ("hello") is showing but not in php" — What are you doing to look at the PHP? The only place that you appear to be examining it is by looking at the Ajax response text where you say it *does* show up.

Comment: Why should you run b.php alone?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you are visiting b.php in your browser then it will be blank because you are making a GET request not a POST request.

You could change `$cat = $_REQUEST['cat'];` which will then echo the cat if you provide it in the URL e.g. `b.php?cat=hello` but if you want to keep it as a POST request then you won't be able to do this from your browser alone.

See [HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **dataType** - text. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/